# Who is the client in HTTP?

Tags: http, https, client, httpclient

I know that client is who is able to send request and get a response from the server.

But exactly WHO is the client? WHO can send requests from the server? I need some examples to get a clear idea about http clients.

Answer (score 0):

Clients are anyone that initialize the request and is able to receive the response from the server.

There are many types of clients, like Web Browsers, APIs, Mobile apps, command-line clients, web servers, postman, guzzle and many others.